# How to display ViewStub preview in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0, viewstub

I have a ViewStub like this -

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    <ViewStub
        android:id="@+id/photos"
        android:layout="@layout/add_photos"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/details"
        tools:visibility="visible" />
 ...
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

But the ViewStub is not rendered in the layout preview and design tabs. Using `<include/>` works though.

I am using Android Studio 3.0 Beta 6.

Is there a way to render preview when using ViewStub?

**EDIT:**

Looks like there is a feature request in google issue tracker https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37090997. But no one has looked into it till now. I will still keep the question open if anyone has any workarounds.

Comment: tools:visibility="visible"

Comment: That doesn't work either. I will edit my question. I was trying out tools:visibility and copied the same into the question.

Comment: Did you find the solution?  I am wondering the same.

Answer (score 18):

Add this to the ViewStub:

```
tools:visibility="visible"
```

and declare xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" in your layout.

Comment: Awesome! It's not obvious but `ViewStub` invisible by default